# jquery format the number with one hyphen only

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
$('#mytextid').blur(function(){
  var string = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(string.substring(0,2) + '-' + string.substring(2,9))
});
```

above script is working fine when someone enters numbers like 123456789 to 12-3456789

but I don't know how can i restrict to input the numbers only (no other charaters are allowed) .

please help

thanks

Comment: What should happen when an illegal character is input? Warning? Silently removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to silently removed illegal characters:

```
$('#mytextid').blur(function(){
  var string = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); // Removes anything not in [0-9]
  $(this).val(string.substring(0,2) + '-' + string.substring(2,9))
});
```

To issue a warning instead:

```
$('#mytextid').blur(function(){
  var string = $(this).val();
  if (/[^\d]/.test(string)) { // Contains illegal characters
    // Warning etc. goes here...
  } else {
    $(this).val(string.substring(0,2) + '-' + string.substring(2,9));
  }
});
```

Comment: @alex Thanks, I *never* get there first :)

Comment: @jensgram According to the timestamp, we posted in the same second.

Comment: @alex Well, it seems you're right on this one. But next time... :)

Answer (score 2):

This will drop all non numeric numbers on `blur()`.

```
$('#mytextid').blur(function(){
  var string = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
  $(this).val(string.substring(0,2) + '-' + string.substring(2,9))
});
```